# auto image slider is working in desktop but its not working in mobile device

Tags: jquery, html, css

The below code is my html for auto image slide. Its working fine in desktop version.But its not working in mobile device

```
<div id="slider1">
    <figure>
        <img src="${context:layout/images/action1.jpeg}"/>
        <img src="${context:layout/images/action2.jpeg}"/>
        <img src="${context:layout/images/action3.jpeg}"/>
        <img src="${context:layout/images/action4.jpeg}"/>
        <img src="${context:layout/images/action5.jpeg}"/>
    </figure>
</div>
```

This css for android device

```
@keyframes slidy {
    0%  { left: 0%; }
    20% { left: 0%; }
    25% { left: -100%; }
    45% { left: -100%; }
    50% { left: -200%; }
    70% { left: -200%; }
    75% { left: -300%; }
    95% { left: -300%; }
    100% { left: -400%; }
}
```

This css for iphone device

```
@-webkit-keyframes slidy {
    0%  { left: 0%; }
    20% { left: 0%; }
    25% { left: -100%; }
    45% { left: -100%; }
    50% { left: -200%; }
    70% { left: -200%; }
    75% { left: -300%; }
    95% { left: -300%; }
    100% { left: -400%; }
}
```

CSS for auto image slide

```
div#slider1 { 
    overflow: hidden; 
}
div#slider1 figure img { 
    width: 20%; 
    float: left; 
    height: 150px;
}
div#slider1 figure { 
    position: relative;
    width: 500%;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 0;
    animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The property `animation: 30s slidy infinite;` is not working without prefrix in webkit (chrome/safari), so you need to add `-webkit-animation: 30s slidy infinite;`

Comment: I have tried it, but its not slide and just show first image only

Comment: Its working fine in android device, but not working in iphone device.If u have any tips pls share it to me.

Comment: You put 30s, it's a very long time to wait, did you wait?